# How to lookup Email based on given User name (not current user)

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to populate the custom Email field of all the records of the account object. Based on a custom field MName which is a lookup to the User object, do a lookup to the User object and get the email and populate the email__c in the Account object. I need this bulkified because there can be many account records to do this on.

Here is what I have attempted but am very new so this may be very far from where I want to be.

Thanks

```
    for(Account acc :Trigger.New)
 {
    List<User> users = New List<User>();
    for(User currUser : users) 
    {
        if (currUser.MName == acc.Name)
        {
            acc.Email = currUser.Email;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Your question heading says(not current user) and in your code you are doing some `curruser`, the question is not clear

Comment: To me, wouldn't you be better off using a Formula field? You could literally use a Formula field that would look at the `MName__c` field (your lookup to the User object) and return the e-mail address of the User? This would do what you want it to do, but also `email__c` would manage itself and you wouldn't need a Batch class or something to populate existing Account records.

Comment: Good point but I am looking for the code itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try the below code hope this helps you :**

else you can create a formula field as suggested by @Poet

```
Set<Id> setuserId = new Set<Id>();
Map<Id, Email> mapUserIdToEmail = new Map<Id, Email>();
List<Account> lstAccount = new List<Account>();
for(Account objAcc : Trigger.new){
    if(objAcc.MName__c != null)
        setuserId.add(objAcc.MName__c);
}

for(User objUser : [SELECT Id, Email FROM User WHERE Id IN : setuserId]){
    mapUserIdToEmail.put(objUser.Id, objUser.Email);
}   

for(Account objAcc : Trigger.new){
    if(mapUserIdToEmail.containsKey(objAcc.MName__c))
        lstAccount.add(new Account(Id = objAcc.Id, email__c = mapUserIdToEmail.get(objAcc.MName__c)));
}

update lstAccount;
```

Comment: Looks good. I will have to try it out. Many thanks